# Login in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to implement very basic authentication in Symfony2. Here are main parts of the code I really don't see any problem

***EDIT***
complete security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:    ^/login
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            stateless:  true
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

This works fine, anonymous user is always redirected to loginAction controller.

***EDIT***
Here is the complete code

```
<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class SecurityController extends Controller {

    public function loginAction() {

        $providerKey = 'secured_area';
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('test', 'test', $providerKey, array('ROLE_USER'));
        $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fronthomepage'));

    }
}
```

I don't see any problem, anonymous user is redirected to loginAction, there is created authenticated user, saved to token and than redirected to secured area as an authenticated user. Unfortunately my code ends with redirect loop which looks like security firewall doesn't accept user as authenticated. Do you see any problem?

Comment: Please, can you dump all your security.yml code and all your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your controller job is to render just form but not to populate security context. Symfony2 security firewall will do that for you automatically. You don't need to handle it unless you want to build you own [custom authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html).

> In other words, your job is to display the login form and any login
>   errors that may have occurred, but the security system itself takes
>   care of checking the submitted username and password and
>   authenticating the user.

Please read this [document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) for clear picture.

If you want to do some custom stuff when a user logs in, in Symfony2 you have to add an event listener that will fire after the user successfully logged in. The event that is fired is `security.interactive_login` and to hook to it you have to specify this in `services.yml` file form your bundle `Resources/config` directory:

Comment: Thank you for response. I need to have authentication without login form. Authentication will be based on URL where it launches 3rd party authentication independent to symfony. What I need is to have ability create user manually. I was reading custom authentication, it looks like really big solution for such small task.

Comment: ah ok. I got you. But test user which you are authenticating is not defined in providers->in_memory->users list. So, redirecting is infinite. try this, $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('user', 'userpass', $providerKey, array('ROLE_USER'));

Comment: I changed the line and it ends with redirect loop. Anonymous user is redirected to login controller, it creates user token there but next redirection fails because firewall doesn't consider user as authenticated. It looks like my token is not saved. I have already tried to save it to session like this $this->container->get('request')->getSession()->set('_security_secured-area', serialize($token)) but it was not better

Comment: back, read this http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/security/authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need an actual user object before setting an authenticated user.  I did something like this:

```
class BaseController

protected function setUser($userName)
{
    if (is_object($userName)) $user = $userName;
    else
    {
        $userProvider = $this->get('zayso_core.user.provider');
        // Need try/catch here
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($userName);
    }
    $providerKey = 'secured_area';
    $providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('zayso_core.provider.key'); // secured_area

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    return $user;
}
```

However doing something like this bypasses much of the security system and is not recommended.  I also wanted to use a 3rd party authentication system (Janrain).  I looked at the authentication system and initially could not make heads or tails out of it.  This was before the cookbook entry existed.

I know it seems overkill but once you work through things then it starts to make more sense.  And you get access to a bunch of nifty security functions.  It took me quite some time to start to understand the authentication system but it was worth it in the end.

Hints:
1.  Work through the cook book backward.  I had a real hard time understanding what was going on but I started with adding a new firewall to security.yml and then adding the alias for my security factory.  I then sort of traced through what the factory was being asked to do.  From there I got the listener to fire up and again traced through the calls.  Finally the authentication manager comes into play.  Again, time consuming, but worth it in the end.  Learned a lot.

1. One thing that drove me crazy is that classes are scattered all over the place.  And the naming leaves something to be desired.  Very hard to get an overview.  I ended up making my own authentication bundle then putting everything under security.
2. If you want another example of a working bundle then take a look at: https://github.com/cerad/cerad/tree/master/src/Cerad/Bundle/JanrainBundle